# Как правильно с помощью MPI_Send и MPI_Resv осуществить цикличний сдвиг данних с шагом один

Tags: mpi

Вот мой код

```
[![#include <windows.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "mpi.h"
#include "pt4.h"
void Solve()
{
    Task("MPIBegin18");
    int flag;
    MPI_Initialized(&flag);
    if (flag == 0)
        return;
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        MPI_Status s;
    int n;
    pt >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
       MPI_Send(&n, 1, MPI_INT, (i + 1) % size, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }


            int n1;
        for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
        {

            MPI_Recv(&n1, 1, MPI_INT, (size + (i - 1)) % size, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &s);

             pt << n1;
        }



    }][1]][1]
```

Почему в каждом процессе выводит одно и тоже число?

Comment: Вижу задание, вижу код, а где сформулирована Ваша проблема? Гляньте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: оно в любом процессе выводит одно и тоже число